# Facebook in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an iPhone app,in this i have an option for sharing my posts with face book(i am just passing the user id of facebook user and my server side developer do the posting part)
I am able to take the user id while log in in face book
But problem is-after the user authenticate from facebook,"post on your behalf" is not coming in the app
(i am using ios6  SDK)
(i have created my app in facebook with checked that public_action from graph)
I have gone through the tutorials(scrumptious) given in facebook developer page,but could not make it

Here are my code-If any one find the error or missing part,please help me to clear that

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder

@property (strong, nonatomic) FBSession *session;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navBar;
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI;
@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#define APP_ID @"fd725FDE45a44198a5b8ad3f7a0ffa09"


@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize session = _session;



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {


     return [self.session handleOpenURL:url];


 }



 - (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {

   NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_location",
                        @"user_birthday",
                        @"user_likes",
                        @"email",
                        @"publish_action",
                        nil];
   return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                      allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState state,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                     [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                         state:state error:error];
                                 }];


      }

     - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                  state:(FBSessionState)state
                  error:(NSError *)error
     {

    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen: {
             FBCacheDescriptor *cacheDescriptor = [FBFriendPickerViewController    cacheDescriptor];
        [cacheDescriptor prefetchAndCacheForSession:session];
       }
        break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed: {
                    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

        [self performSelector:@selector(showLoginView)
                   withObject:nil
                   afterDelay:0.5f];
       }
        break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed: {
                    [self performSelector:@selector(showLoginView)
                   withObject:nil
                   afterDelay:0.5f];
        }
        break;
        default:
        break;
        }


        }



   @end
```

**InviteFriendViewController.h**

```
    @interface InviteFriendViewController : 
    -(IBAction)fbfrnds:(id)sender;
    - (void)updateView;
    @end
```

**InviteFriendViewController.m**

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
   [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

     userid = [defaults objectForKey:@"userid"];

      AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

     if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
      appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];


       if (appDelegate.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState status,
                                                         NSError *error) {
            [self updateView];
        }
         ];
         }
         }
         }




     -(void)facebookReteriveInformation:(NSDictionary *)dictnry{



       FriendlistViewController *friends = [[FriendlistViewController      alloc]initWithNibName:@"FriendlistViewController" bundle:nil];

           friends.token = string;

      [self.navigationController pushViewController:friends animated:YES];


       }



     -(IBAction)fbfrnds:(id)sender{



     sharedClass=[SharedClass sharedInstance];

     appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;


      AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

     if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {

       [self updateView];
        } else {
    if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    }

    [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {
        [self updateView];
     }];
      }

    NSLog(@"string issss %@",string);


       }


    - (void)updateView {
     AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
     if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {

    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
              appDelegate.session.accessToken];

    NSLog(@"string issss %@",string);
    NSString *urlstrng;
    if(flag == 1){
        urlstrng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@",
                    string];
        [self dataFetching:urlstrng];
        }


       } else {

    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
              appDelegate.session.accessToken];
    NSString *urlstrng;
    if(flag == 1){
        urlstrng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@",
                    string];
        [self dataFetching:urlstrng];
       }
       }
       }

     -(void)dataFetching:(NSString*)strng1{

       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strng1];
       ProfileConnector *obj = [[ProfileConnector alloc] init];
      obj.delegate1 = self;
       [obj parsingJson:url];

       }


       - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
     }




     - (void) performPublishAction:(void (^)(void)) action {
   if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] ==  NSNotFound) {
     [FBSession.activeSession reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray  arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                                defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                             completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,  NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
                     action();
                                                 }
                                             }];
       } else {
    action();
       }

        }



        }

       @end
```

Comment: At first place you have said "my server side developer do the posting part". Then you say, ""post on your behalf" is not coming in the app". What do you actually want??

Comment: Only if it is authenticated(post on your behalf),the server side can post in users FB account

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the 3.1 version of Facebook SDK, `openActiveSessionWithPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:` is not supposed to be used and the old way of doing it does not seem to be functional anymore; from the [3.1 migration documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/);

> ...you will need to remove usage of openActiveSessionWithPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler: and replace it with openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler: (or even more simply, openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI).
>
> Later, when your app needs to publish back to Facebook, you should use reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:defaultAudience:completionHandler: to seek the additional permissions.

Even more details available at the [migration docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/).