# How to make recent images on top of UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

In my iPhone app, user can select photo from device while uploading,
When the click select photo-the `UIImagePickerController` comes. But its order is recent photos on bottom, so the user have to scroll a lot to select their recent pictures,How can I make it as recent pics on top of `UIImagePickerController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do that
just use this in imagepicker

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

Answer (score 3):

With UIImagePickerController it is not possible. However you can overcome this by using ALAssetLibrary and create your controller.

If you are running short in time I will recommend you to use [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController), change the code of [ElcAssetTablePicker.m](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController/blob/master/Classes/ELCAssetTablePicker.m) **preparePhotos** method.

Add following code to it

```
if(self.tableView.contentSize.height > self.tableView.frame.size.height)
{
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height);
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
}
```

And bingo you will see it will scroll to bottom of the table. So user can see recent photos directly.

Let me know in case of any query.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it.

There is no way to adjust the photolibrary data in `UIImagePickerController`.

If you need this you need to rely on any third party api's or you need to write your on picker which sorts images using their timestamps or asseturl's. (Currently no third party library is available for doing this)

Comment: thank u man...happy to see u again :)

Comment: @NithinMK: with pleasure dude :)

Comment: Hey man..i need one help

Comment: @NithinMK: you can ask dude :)

Comment: bro..have u ever implemented tumblr in iphone app,i have searched alot and couldnt find a solution,if you can please help me

and also,i have  a problem with facebook authentication,please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973635/facebook-in-iphone-app