# Facebook SDK issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have created a facebook authentication in my iPhone app, I followed  [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/) tutorial
for that. But except one line of code,that is

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

When I use this, it is an error shows:

> No visible @interface for 'FBSession' declares the selector
>   handleDidBecomeActive

But still the authentication works fine while I click the logIn button, Problem is my authentication window is just showing "basic info"-i need to access "post on your behalf" also

```
      My authentication window is             I need to authenticate 
              like this                    like this (as in FB tutorial)
```

[image][image]

Cant find out the error, Will it be in app creation in Facebook or my authentication error in iPhone coding. If anyone got the error,please help me to clarify

Comment: Which facebook SDK version are you using? If I remember correctly, `handleDidBecomeActive` is new in Facebook SDK 3.1.

Comment: yep..I am using Facebook iOS 6 SDK(Facebook SDK 3.1.)

Comment: I can't repeat your problem with `handleDidBecomeActive` using the 3.1 SDK, my test project using it compiles without any warnings or errors importing only `<FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`.

Comment: so it might be the issue in creating the app in developer.facebook
Please let me know the steps for that,thus i can find out my fault

Comment: And you get "Post on your Behalf" ???

Comment: Wrote up an answer with the info instead of adding more comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a test project, I cannot repeat your error message;

```
No visible @interface for 'FBSession' declares the selector handleDidBecomeActive
```

when compiling with Facebook SDK 3.1.1 (don't have 3.1 handy to test). It would seem to be something version related since the `handleDidBecomeActive` is new in the 3.1 version and the message is related to the compiler not seeing the selector.

Also, regarding your permission problem; the permission system has been altered in the 3.1 version to not allow you to request read and write permissions at the same time. Quote from the [3.1 migration documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/);

> You are now required to request read and publish permission *separately* (and in that order). Most likely, you will request the read permissions for personalization when the app starts and the user first logs in. Later, if appropriate, your app can request publish permissions when it intends to post data to Facebook.

I can request read permission on login (which is what you're seeing), but as you're seeing you cannot request post permissions at the same time. If I, as the SDK is hinting, later request that permission, it seems to work as it should.

Comment: I have posted entier code in this question,please take a look

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973635/facebook-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

I used the code you written only in iOS 6 and above.
you should try this code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]integerValue] >= __IPHONE_6_0) {
        [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
    }

}
```

Comment: If you don't call `handleDidBecomeActive`, you'll need to implement `applicationDidBecomeActive:` in some other way to work correctly with app switching.

Comment: it shows the same error :(

You think this is the reason for my issue(no "Post on Your behalf") ??

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I find this might help someone that is encountering the same problem so I am posting my solution here.  I am using FacebookSDK v3.1 and experienced the same problem today.  It is because I still have the older FacebookSDK v3.0 path in the Targets Search Paths.  Just make sure the correct FacebookSDK path is entered in the Targets Search Paths and the compiler will not complain.